# Java Script: replace function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have values in my HTML like below

```
348419 ( 26% )
99425 ( -11% )
```

I would like them to change the text color depending on the values in parenthesis. If the value is positive, it should be displayed in Green, else red.

I'm using the below code, however the text is always displayed in Green as all the starting values such as `348419,99425` are positive. It is not able to parse the values in brackets. 
Can someone pls help.

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID td');

for ( var i=0; i<cells.length; i++ ) {
var cell    = cells[i];
var html    = cell.innerHTML;
var changed = html.replace(/([+-]?(\d|\.)+)/, function(x) {
    var color = (+x) < 0 ? 'red' : 'green';
    return '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + x + '</span>';
});

cell.innerHTML = changed;
}
```

HTML is like this:

```
<table id="tableID">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Column heading 1</th>
<th>Column heading 2</th>
<th>Column heading 3</th>
<th>Column heading 4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>348419 ( 26% )</td>
<td>99425 ( -1% )</td>
<td>946574 ( 0% )</td>
<td>99485 ( -11% )</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>33348419 ( 36% )</td>
<td>746733 (-32%)</td>
<td>36689279 (0)</td>
<td>27678 (28%)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>7734190 ( 6% )</td>
 <td>333879 ( 35% )</td>
 <td>3878 (-10% )</td>
 <td>4419 ( -99% )</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: add the html markup plz

Comment: Try this: if(cell.indexOf('-') !== -1 ){ //greeen cell = cell.replace('this string', 'this green string'); }else { cell = cell.replace('this string', 'this red string'); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the regular expression you are using. To retrieve only the number in the parenthesis, use `/\(\s*([+-]?(\d)+)(?:%\s*\))/`. Then the function would look like this

```
var changed = html.replace(/\(\s*([+-]?(\d)+)(?:%\s*\))/, function(match, group) {
    var color = (+group) < 0 ? 'red' : 'green'
    return '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + group + '</span>'
})
```

Comment: this is giving me an error, saying that x is undefined

Comment: the color is changing as expected but it is removing the brackets and percentage sign. Any idea how to fix that pls

Comment: thanks mic4ael, I edited and this worked. Marking this an official answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your round brackets as otherwise they have a special purpose in regex: to *group* items. In addition, you need to allow for whitespace inside the brackets. So your expression becomes `/\(\s*[+-]?[0-9.]+%\s*\)/` instead of `/([+-]?(\d|\.)+)/`

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('#tableID td');

for ( var i=0; i<cells.length; ++i ) {
    var cell    = cells[i]
    var html    = cell.innerHTML
    var changed = html.replace(/\(\s*[+-]?[0-9.]+%\s*\)/, function(x) {
        var color = (+x) < 0 ? 'red' : 'green'
        return '<span style="color: ' + color + '">' + x + '</span>'
    })

    cell.innerHTML = changed
}
```

Comment: @mic4ael thank you, I edited it and now it passes the tests on https://regex101.com/

Comment: sure, but he is trying to retrieve only the value inside the parenthesis

Comment: the only problem that I'm getting is that values inside the parenthesis are in GREEN color irrespective of +ve or -ve values. Can it be fixed pls

Answer (score 1):

The values are string. if you compare the string with numeric comparison operators, it will always be greater than 0. parse your html content in a way that it return only the 26 from "348419 ( 26% )" and -11 from "99425 ( -11% )"

in this code your regex not returning the valid value i.e.

```
"99425 ( -11% )".replace(/([+-]?(\d|\.)+)/, function(x) {console.log(x);})
```

output : x = 99425 which is always a positive integer.

Comment: *parse your html content in a way that it return only the 26 from "348419 ( 26% )* And how would I do that, is the question.

Comment: Try this "348419 ( -26% )".replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').trim().split('  ').pop()